# dynamically assign variable in lua through a function parameter

Tags: lua

Is there any way to dynamically assign a global variables through a function parameter, so I don't have to create a ton of ifs and/or twin functions to achieve the same result?

Example:

```lua
Generic = {}

function GenericFunction(var)
    local value = { v1 = 1, v2 = 2 }

    return loadstring([[Generic.]] .. var .. [[ = value]])()
end
```

Comment: I cannot follow you. What is the purpose of this? and why do you use loadstring to simply assign a value to a variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Lua, `foo.bar` is just sugar for `foo['bar']`. As such, there's a much simpler solution for what you want: just do `Generic[var] = value`.